# Cross Tab Report - How to Control Row Order?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using a Cross Tab Report with rows with names like 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q7', 'Q10' etc.

However, they're in alphabetical order such as:

```
Q1
Q10
Q2
Q7
```

However, I want:

```
Q1
Q2
Q7
Q10
```

Is there any way to specify the order of rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a crystal formula to return the Q1, Q2, etc as only the number and as an integer. Group on this formula in the cross-tab, but use the original field as the Group name.

Comment: Not as quick as the first poster, but more versatile.

Comment: I actually find this solution quicker than modifying the original query.

Answer (score 2):

Why not change the query to have the Q1 output as Q01?

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't be acceptable to the user, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found after few days of frustration. The solution works for me and hopefully [it will help others](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101031210051AANfWsv)